# How to reduce space between words in gsm package

Tags: spacing, kerning, amsbook

I used gms package (a special package of AMS, provided for their Graduate Studies in Maths serie) to write a math book.

I got a problem with space, and then I want to narrow a line by reduce the space between words.

Here is a MWE :

```
 \documentclass{gsm-l}
 \usepackage[papersize={160mm,240mm},inner=20mm, outer=15mm, vmargin=15mm]{geometry}
 \usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
 \begin{document}
  Vì $BB_0\perp CA$; $CC_0\perp BA$ nên $A, H, B_0, C_0$ cùng 
  thuộc một đường tròn (3).
 \end{document}
```

And this is what we get after compiling
[image: Letter space]

I want to reduce the space between the words so that "tròn (3)" will go up to the first line.

So what should I do?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: the only place i can see where spacing might reasonably be decreased is around the `\perp`.  if you enclose it in braces -- `{\perp}` -- it will be treated as an "ordinary" symbol rather than as a binary operator, and almost all space will be omitted.  you can also force the last two text elements to hold together by replacing the space before "(3)" by a tie `~`.  (but there still may not be enough room on the line to accommodate the extra text.)

Answer (score 1):

the only place i can see where spacing might reasonably be decreased is
around the `\perp`.

if you enclose it in braces -- `{\perp}` -- it will be treated as an "ordinary" symbol rather than as a binary operator, and almost all space will be omitted. you can also force the last two text elements to hold together by replacing the space before "(3)" by a tie `~`.

a bit more space could be gained by using `\noindent`, but that may not be appropriate.

but there still may not be enough room on the line to accommodate the extra text.  there's a limit to the amount of text that can be put on one line.